# Presto can't fetch content in HIVE table

Tags: hive, presto

My environment:
hadoop 1.0.4
hive 0.12
hbase 0.94.14
presto 0.56

All packages are installed on pseudo machine. The services are not running on localhost but
on the host name with a static IP.

presto conf:

```
coordinator=false
datasources=jmx,hive
http-server.http.port=8081
presto-metastore.db.type=h2
presto-metastore.db.filename=/root
task.max-memory=1GB
discovery.uri=http://<HOSTNAME>:8081
```

In presto cli I can get the table in hive successfully:

```
presto:default> show tables;
       Table
-------------------
ht1
k_business_d_
k_os_business_d_
...
tt1_
(11 rows)

Query 20140114_072809_00002_5zhjn, FINISHED, 1 node
Splits: 2 total, 2 done (100.00%)
0:11 [11 rows, 291B] [0 rows/s, 26B/s]
```

but when I try to query data from any table the result always be empty: (no error information)

```
presto:default> select * from k_business_d_;
 key | business | business_name | collect_time | numofalarm | numofhost | test
-----+----------+---------------+--------------+------------+-----------+------
(0 rows)

Query 20140114_072839_00003_5zhjn, FINISHED, 1 node
Splits: 1 total, 1 done (100.00%)
0:02 [0 rows, 0B] [0 rows/s, 0B/s]
```

If I executed the same sql in HIVE, the result show there are 1 row in the table.

```
hive> select * from k_business_d_;
OK
9223370648089975807|2   2       æµ‹è¯•æœº       2014-01-04 00:00:00     NULL    1.0         NULL
Time taken: 2.574 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Why presto can't fetch from HIVE tables?

Comment: What file format does your table use? Please show the output of "DESCRIBE FORMATTED table" in Hive.

Comment: Thanks for your help. it's an external table on HBASE

Comment: hive> DESCRIBE FORMATTED k_business_d_;
OK
# col_name              data_type               comment

key                     string                  from deserializer
business                int                     from deserializer
business_name           string                  from deserializer
collect_time            string                  from deserializer
numofalarm              double                  from deserializer
numofhost               double                  from deserializer
test                    double                  from deserializer

Comment: # Detailed Table Information
Database:               default
Owner:                  root
CreateTime:             Thu Jan 09 16:04:37 CST 2014
LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN
Protect Mode:           None
Retention:              0
Location:               hdfs://allinone:9000/user/hive/warehouse/k_business_d_
Table Type:             EXTERNAL_TABLE
Table Parameters:
        EXTERNAL                TRUE
        hbase.table.name        K_BUSINESS_D
        storage_handler         org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler
        transient_lastDdlTime   1389254677

Comment: # Storage Information
SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe
InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableInputFormat
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HivePassThroughOutputFormat

Comment: Compressed:             No
Num Buckets:            -1
Bucket Columns:         []
Sort Columns:           []
Storage Desc Params:
        hbase.columns.mapping   :key,DIM:BUSINESS,DIM:BUSINESS_NAME,DIM:COLLECT_                                                                                                             TIME,KPI:NUMOFALARM,KPI:NUMOFHOST,KPI:TEST
        serialization.format    1

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this is an external table that uses HBase via `org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler`. This is not supported yet, but one mailing list post indicates it might be possible if you copy the appropriate jars to the Hive plugin directory: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/presto-users/U7vx8PhnZAA/9edzcK76tD8J